# Python - insufficent permissions to create dir in Program Files/installdir on Windows

Tags: python, windows, file, permissions

I've just finished a program to the point of freezing it for distribution.

On Windows, I use cx_Freeze to make an MSI installer. By default, this installs the program to C:/Program Files/(program name), as is usual on Windows.

When the program starts up, it creates a "temp" folder in its installation directory. This is used throughout runtime to hold in-use files and packages for extraction (It actually works as an installer for web apps for my MVC platform).

This has always worked fine throughout development but now results in the program immediately crashing when installed to Program Files because it doesn't seem to have permissions to create the "temp" folder. Installing to a directory like Documents, or the root of C:/, works fine.

How do I get Python the necessary permissions to create C:/Program Files/(program name)/temp ?

Ilmiont

Comment: It would be preferable to create those temporary files in the user profile folder. You can check what  `echo %TEMP%` gives in command line prompt.

Comment: Yes, ideally, but the program needs to be multiplatform. Going relative to install directory keeps it working with the same code on win32 and Linux. I should have mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this instead:

```
import os
import sys

homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    datadir = os.sep.join([homedir, 'Application Data', 'MyApp'])
else:
    datadir = os.sep.join([homedir, '.myapp'])
```

If *C:\Program Files\MyApp* is preferred, then the installer should probably set the permissions for a directory to avoid problems with permissions. I didn't find this kind of feature from *cx_Freeze*.

Your program could ask the user that the program should be executed as an administrator if it detects that the directory has wrong permissions. It could then fix the permissions when run as an administrator.

Comment: Thank you. For now, I think I'll just prompt users to run as admin if it fails to make the directory. Is it possible to force run as admin, without using the "Run as administrator" option in the exe's properties? I.e. Programs like WampSever always run as admin

Comment: No, don't ask the user to run your program elevated. Spend the time to learn how Windows works. Store files where they are meant to be stored.

Comment: If I were to use that third option i.e. run as administrator to fix the permissions (I would really prefer to avoid that), I would probably try to find out how to launch a second small program with elevated privileges that would not do anything else except changing the permissions for that directory.

Comment: It would be better to use `os.environ['APPDATA']` or `os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']`. It would be even better to call the recommended shell APIs. You can add a module that abstracts system and user directories in a cross-platform way, such as using Windows [known folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911) or Linux [XDG base directories](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest).

Comment: Forcing administrator access just to store data in "Program Files" is wrong. Don't do this, but if you must then it works by [embedding an application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx#vistauac_topic6f) that requests `highestAvailable` or `requireAdministrator` execution level. Only tools and applications that genuinely need administrator access should require it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I know it's bad just to force run admin for this and will definitely take the time in the future to refine this using actual system directories. Again, thanks for the advice